# pandas drop duplicates of one column with criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
A   B
239616412   none
239616414   name2
239616417   none
239616417   none
239616417   none
239616418   name1
239616418   none
239616428   name1
239616429   none
239616429   none
239616429   name1
```

I want to delete duplicates of the column A, and I want to keep the row that has any kind of name in it (!= none, basically) in column B, but if the only value in all of the duplicates is none, I still want to keep it (like `239616417`).

It should reduce to:

```
A   B
239616412   none
239616414   name2
239616417   none
239616418   name1
239616428   name1
239616429   name1
```

Comment: If there are multiple non-none names in `B` would you want to keep the duplicates?

Comment: I'd rather keep them but they also can be deleted, if the code is easier to do that way. There's only around 5 of these said non-none duplicates so I can manage them.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a solution.

Firstly sort on column 'B':

```
df.sort('B', inplace=True)

df
Out[24]: 
            A      B
5   239616418  name1
7   239616428  name1
10  239616429  name1
1   239616414  name2
0   239616412    NaN
2   239616417    NaN
3   239616417    NaN
4   239616417    NaN
6   239616418    NaN
8   239616429    NaN
9   239616429    NaN
```

Then drop duplicates w.r.t. column 'A':

```
df.drop_duplicates('A', inplace=True)

df
Out[26]: 
            A      B
5   239616418  name1
7   239616428  name1
10  239616429  name1
1   239616414  name2
0   239616412    NaN
2   239616417    NaN
```

You can re-sort the data frame to get exactly what you want:

```
df.sort(inplace=True)

df
Out[30]: 
            A      B
0   239616412    NaN
1   239616414  name2
2   239616417    NaN
5   239616418  name1
7   239616428  name1
10  239616429  name1
```

Comment: It looks like the first should now be `df.sort_values` and the last `df.sort_index`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to drop any duplicates, this should work.  The sort will place all valid entries after NAs, so they will have preference in the `drop_duplicate` logic.

```
df.loc[df['B'] == 'none', 'B'] = np.nan
df = df.sort(['A','B']).drop_duplicates(subset='A')
```

If you'd rather keep duplicate valid values, you could do something like this, which splits the data into nulls/not-null, and recombines.

```
valids = df.dropna().drop_duplicates()

invalids = df[pd.isnull(df['B'])].drop_duplicates()
invalids = invalids[~invalids['A'].isin(valids['A'])]

df = pd.concat([valids, invalids])
```